# Implementation java game with slick2d on website

Tags: java, slick2d

I have problem with implementation game on website.
I have tried to do like in this site :  http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet

I'm receiving this error:

```
ERROR:MainPackage.TGame
java.lang.InstantiationException: MainPackage.TGame
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer.init(AppletGameContainer.java:124)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:766)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.run(AppletLoader.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Fatal error occured (8): Unable to create game container
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create game container
at org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer.init(AppletGameContainer.java:148)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:766)
at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.run(AppletLoader.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is mine MainPackage.TGame

```
package MainPackage;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class TGame extends StateBasedGame {

        public TotalPunkty suma = new TotalPunkty();
        public static final int menu = 0;
        public static final int game = 1;
        public static final int high = 2;
        public static final int about = 3;
        public static final int howto = 4;
        public static final int over = 5;

        BasicGameState G = new Game(game, suma);
        public BasicGameState O = new Over(over, suma);

        public static String title = "TGame";


        public TGame(String name) {
                super(name);
                this.addState(new Menu(menu));
                this.addState(G);
                this.addState(new High(high));
                this.addState(new About(about));
                this.addState(new HowTo(howto));
                this.addState(O);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
                AppGameContainer MainWindow;

                try {
                        MainWindow = new AppGameContainer(new TGame(title));
                        MainWindow.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
                        MainWindow.setShowFPS(true);
                        MainWindow.setTargetFrameRate(60);
                        MainWindow.start();
                } catch(SlickException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
                this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
                this.getState(game).init(gc, this);
                this.getState(high).init(gc, this);
                this.getState(about).init(gc, this);
                this.getState(howto).init(gc, this);
                this.getState(over).init(gc, this);
                this.enterState(menu);
        }

}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me or just give me some tips how to fix that. :)

Comment: I can highly recommend that you take slick2d questions to java-gaming.org, since that's where the people hang out that not only use this tech but also the one(s) that actually built it. The slick2d wiki also contains plenty of information; glancing through it I see MainGame being used as the game base class, not StateBasedGame.